# What does `&==;` mean with regard to Python Django and bypassing WAFs?

Tags: python, waf, django

I'm reading someone's slides on bypassing WAFs.

> - `&==;` : Python Django between parameters;
> - `FooBar==POST verb` : Apache with PHP;
> - `<%I%M%U011e>==<IMG>` : IIS ASP Classic;
> - `;/path1 ;foo/path2;bar/;==/path1/path2/` : Apache Tomcat;

On one page he mentions the string `&==;-`. Does anyone know the meaning of "between parameters"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read it as: `&` == `;`

This bullet point just means that the Django framework for Python parses both an ampersand (`&`) and a semicolon (`;`) equally as valid separators of query parameters in a given URL.

Consequently, the following URLs would be treated identically:

```
https://example.com/foo/bar?x=y&name=peter&debug=1
https://example.com/foo/bar?x=y;name=peter;debug=1
```

This is remarkable because other frameworks might not recognize the semicolon as a separator and read the second query string as a single parameter `x` with the value `y;name=peter;debug=1`. This behavior might in turn confuse WAFs which is likely why it's listed on your slides.